# Calculate grouped average of columns in pandas dataframe for non zero elements based on time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

Hello I would like to calculate the average of days column for each Name group at each Time. The average at each Time for each group should be calculated only based on the elements of the rows of the Days which are larger than 0. Any feedback would be highly appreciated ..

```
Name       Time        Days    Average
 
John    2021-12-02      0        0
John    2021-12-03      2        0 
John    2021-12-05      9        2
John    2021-12-07      0       5.5
John    2021-12-10     10       5.5
Larry   2021-12-02     20        0
Jim     2021-12-09     20        0
Jim     2021-12-10     20       20
Jim     2021-12-12     40       20
Jim     2021-12-12      0       26.6
Juli    2021-11-09      0        0
Juli    2021-11-10      0        0
Juli    2021-11-12     40        0
Juli    2021-11-18      0       40
Juli    2021-11-12      0       40
Juli    2021-11-18      2       40
Juli    2021-11-19      0       21
```

Comment: please share dataframe creator code

Answer (score 1):

First replace `0` to missing values and then use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with lambda function for [`Series.expanding`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.expanding.html) with `mean` and [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), last replace `NaN`s to `0` by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['Avg'] = (df.assign(Days = df['Days'].replace(0,np.nan))
               .groupby('Name')['Days']
               .transform(lambda x: x.expanding().mean().shift())
               .fillna(0))
print (df)
     Name        Time  Days  Average        Avg
0    John  2021-12-02     0      0.0   0.000000
1    John  2021-12-03     2      0.0   0.000000
2    John  2021-12-05     9      2.0   2.000000
3    John  2021-12-07     0      5.5   5.500000
4    John  2021-12-10    10      5.5   5.500000
5   Larry  2021-12-02    20      0.0   0.000000
6     Jim  2021-12-09    20      0.0   0.000000
7     Jim  2021-12-10    20     20.0  20.000000
8     Jim  2021-12-12    40     20.0  20.000000
9     Jim  2021-12-12     0     26.6  26.666667
10   Juli  2021-11-09     0      0.0   0.000000
11   Juli  2021-11-10     0      0.0   0.000000
12   Juli  2021-11-12    40      0.0   0.000000
13   Juli  2021-11-18     0     40.0  40.000000
14   Juli  2021-11-12     0     40.0  40.000000
15   Juli  2021-11-18     2     40.0  40.000000
16   Juli  2021-11-19     0     21.0  21.000000
```

Comment: I would like the average to be calculated only taken into account non zero Days elements the solution provided uses all the elements to calculate the average for each group which is not what i would like to do i.e for row 4 for John uses row 0,1,2 and 3 I would like to use only elements with non zero days element row1 and 2 and not row 0 and 3

Comment: @konrac - yes, and for it is replaced `0` to `np.nan`, then are not used rows `0,3`, because filled by missing values. So not sure if understand what is problem.